# How to declare function in angular 8 controller for external call?

Tags: angular, angular8

I need to declare function `initialData(data)` in my angular application (webview) for mobile application sending data through this function.

I tried

```
declare function initialData(data): any;
```

before `@component` but it doesn't work. My mobile application return error

> *function not found*.

Is there any idea or any question please leave in comment, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the export keyword

```
export function initialData(data): any {
}
```

Although you shouldn't need to do this in Angular.
If you truly want to share a function across components/services then you should [declare a service](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#delegate-complex-component-logic-to-services), and then inject that service into the components/services you want to use it in.

You can learn more about services in the [documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. can you explain more about declare a service. I'm very new to angular.

Comment: @eightpaws services are a core part of how angular applications use and share data. You declare a service (along with the functionality you wish to share) and then inject that service into your components. You could learn more about them by reading the documentation and following the tutorials. I've updated my answer with a link to the relevant documentation.